# cumsum on subset of pandas df columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
Date       Week    Value1   Value2   Value3

2022-01-01    1     -10       20       30
2022-01-02    1      -5        25       20
2022-01-03    1     0         15       NaN
2022-01-04    1     5         7        10
2022-01-05    1     7         10       15
2022-01-06    1    10        5       NaN
```

I am looking to perform a cumulative sum such that the resulting DF is as follows

```
Date        Week Value1   Value2   Value3
2022-01-03   1    -15       60       50
2022-01-05   1    22       22       25
```

Essentially `Value3` has `NaN` values. No other column has it. I am looking to total up all values for the 3 `Value` columns between each `NaN` encountered in `Value3`. I am also looking to keep `Date` and `Week` of the row where I encountered the `NaN` value as is (so cumsum is applied only to Value columns)
I have tried so far (some variations of the below) but w/o success.

```
df.groupby(['Date','Week'])['Value1', 'Value2','Value3'].apply(lambda x: x.isna().cumsum().reset_index(drop=True))
```

But havent got the desired result using this.
Any ideas on how this can be achieved?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a greoupby on a cumulative number of NaNs in Value3:

```
df.groupby(df['Value3'].shift().isna().cumsum()).agg({'Date':'last', 'Week':'last', 'Value1':'sum', 'Value2':'sum', 'Value3':'sum'}).reset_index(drop = True)
```

output:

```
    Date       Week Value1  Value2  Value3
0   2022-01-03  1   -15     60      50.0
1   2022-01-06  1   22      22      25.0
```